# How to handle TextField validation in password in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I created a login page and I need to add these things to my password. How do I do it **with validation alert message?**

- Minimum 1 Upper case
- Minimum 1 lowercase
- Minimum 1 Numeric Number
- Minimum 1 Special Character
- Common Allow Character ( ! @ # $ & * ~ )

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to use Regular Expression to validate the structure.

```
 bool validateStructure(String value){
        String  pattern = r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$';
        RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
        return regExp.hasMatch(value);
  }

output: 

    Vignesh123! : true
    vignesh123 : false
    VIGNESH123! : false
    vignesh@ : false
    12345678? : false
```

This function will validate the passed value is having the structure or not.

```
    var _usernameController = TextEditingController();
    String _usernameError;

    ...

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return
        ...
        TextFormField(
          controller: _usernameController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Username", errorText: _usernameError),
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
        ),
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 50.0,
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: validate,
            child: Text(
              "Login",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ...
    }

    ...

    validate(){
        if(!validateStructure(_usernameController.text)){
            setState(() {
                _usernameError = emailError;
                _passwordError = passwordError;
            });
            // show dialog/snackbar to get user attention.
            return;
        }
        // Continue 
    }
```

Comment: is it only way to true, `Vignesh123! : true`.. is this also wokring? `!123viGnesh`

Answer (score 85):

Your regular expression should look like:

```
r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$
```

Here is an explanation:

```
r'^
  (?=.*[A-Z])       // should contain at least one upper case
  (?=.*[a-z])       // should contain at least one lower case
  (?=.*?[0-9])      // should contain at least one digit
  (?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]) // should contain at least one Special character
  .{8,}             // Must be at least 8 characters in length  
$
```

Match above expression with your password string. Using this method-

```
    String? validatePassword(String value) {
    RegExp regex =
        RegExp(r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$');
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter password';
    } else {
      if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
        return 'Enter valid password';
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: how to validate this one? `•Common Allow Character ( ! @ # $ & * ~ )`

Comment: "(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~])"   part of regex will compare common characters of your password string.

Comment: Beware the aliens! The explanation is not describing the same regex. The explanation misses some `?` chars.

Comment: More special characters validation: ```(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~`)\%\-(_+=;:,.<>/?"'[{\]}\|^])```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use TextFormField widget with validator property.

```
TextFormField(
   validator: (value) {
      // add your custom validation here.
      if (value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Please enter some text';
      }
      if (value.length < 3) {
        return 'Must be more than 2 charater';
      }
   },
),
```

Take a look on official docs: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation

Comment: How to check upper and lower and special character as I mention in my question?

Comment: you can use a RegExp rom dart:core package: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-core/RegExp-class.html

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using below flutter plugin.

[wc_form_validators](https://pub.dev/packages/wc_form_validators)

You can use it something like this:

```dart
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Password',
            ),
            validator: Validators.compose([
              Validators.required('Password is required'),
              Validators.patternString(r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$', 'Invalid Password')
            ]),
          ),
```

Its documentation is really good. You can read it for more util functions like this.

Answer (score 3):

**By using extension in dart**

```
extension PasswordValidator on String {
  bool isValidPassword() {
  return RegExp(
        r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$')
    .hasMatch(this);
  }
}
```

You can apply this in your textfield like

```
TextFormField(
  autovalidate: true,
  validator: (input) => input. isValidPassword() ? null : "Check your password...",
)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Flutter Login Validation**

```
  ///creating Username and Password Controller.
  TextEditingController username=TextEditingController();
TextEditingController password=TextEditingController();
  Form(
    child: Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: username,
              validator: (CurrentValue){
                var nonNullValue=CurrentValue??'';
                if(nonNullValue.isEmpty){
                  return ("username is required");
                }
                if(!nonNullValue.contains("@")){
                  return ("username should contains @");
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: password,
              validator: (PassCurrentValue){
                RegExp regex=RegExp(r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$');
                var passNonNullValue=PassCurrentValue??"";
                if(passNonNullValue.isEmpty){
                  return ("Password is required");
                }
                else if(passNonNullValue.length<6){
                  return ("Password Must be more than 5 characters");
                }
                else if(!regex.hasMatch(passNonNullValue)){
                  return ("Password should contain upper,lower,digit and Special character ");
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
              if(Form.of(context)?.validate()?? false){
           Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=>loginpage()));
              }
            }, child: Text("Login"))
          ],
        );
      }
    ),
  )
```

[*in this picture you can see when you Enter inValid username and password it will not Navigate to another page.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEYAX.png)

[*when you Enter Valid Username and Password it will Navigate to another Page.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzUKu.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

here is the complete answer

> Write a Dart program to check whether a string is a valid password. a. A password must have at least ten characters. b. A password
>   consists of only letters and digits. c. A password must contain at
>   least two digits.

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  var password;
  stdout.write("Enter You'r Password: ");
  password=stdin.readLineSync();

   if(password.length>=10 && !password.contains(RegExp(r'\W')) && RegExp(r'\d+\w*\d+').hasMatch(password))
   {
     print(" \n\t$password is Valid Password");
   }
   else
   {
     print("\n\t$password is Invalid Password");

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_pw_validator/flutter_pw_validator.dart';
    
    import 'Card_Creation.dart';
    
    class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
      const SignUp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<SignUp> createState() => _SignUpState();
    }
    
    class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
      TextEditingController _useremail = TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController _userpass = TextEditingController();
      final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _useremail.dispose();
        _userpass.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Center(
                child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        const Text(
                          'Sign Up here....!',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          validator: (value) {
                            var availableValue = value ?? '';
                            if (availableValue.isEmpty) {
                              return ("Username is required");
                            }
                            if (!availableValue.contains("@") ||
                                !availableValue.endsWith("gmail.com")) {
                              return ("Username should be a valid Gmail address");
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          controller: _useremail,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          obscureText: false,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Your email address',
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                borderSide:
                                const BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              borderSide:
                              const BorderSide(color: Colors.greenAccent),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return "Password is required";
                            }
                            // Perform custom password validation here
                            if (value.length < 8) {
                              return "Password must be at least 8 characters long";
                            }
                            if (!value.contains(RegExp(r'[A-Z]'))) {
                              return "Password must contain at least one uppercase letter";
                            }
                            if (!value.contains(RegExp(r'[a-z]'))) {
                              return "Password must contain at least one lowercase letter";
                            }
                            if (!value.contains(RegExp(r'[0-9]'))) {
                              return "Password must contain at least one numeric character";
                            }
                            if (!value.contains(RegExp(r'[!@#\$%^&*()<>?/|}{~:]'))) {
                              return "Password must contain at least one special character";
                            }
    
                            return null; // Password is valid.
                          },
                          controller: _userpass,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                          obscureText: true,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Enter Your password',
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.greenAccent),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
    
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        FlutterPwValidator(
                          controller: _userpass,
                          minLength: 8,
                          uppercaseCharCount: 1,
                          lowercaseCharCount: 1,
                          numericCharCount: 1,
                          specialCharCount: 1,
                          width: 200,
                          height: 150,
                          onSuccess: () {
                            return null; // Password is valid.
                          },
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                  const SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')),
                                );
                                _signup();
                              }
                            },
                            child: const Text('Register'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
    
      void _routing_with_clearfields() {
        _useremail.clear();
        _userpass.clear();
        _snackonsignup();
    
        // Navigate to the next screen using Navigator.
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyCard()),
        );
      }
      void _signup() async {
        try {
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: _useremail.text.trim(), password: _userpass.text);
          _routing_with_clearfields();
        } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
          if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
            print('The password provided is too weak.');
          } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
            print('The account already exists for that email.');
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      }
    
      void _snackonsignup() {
        final snack = SnackBar(
          content: const Text(
            'SignUp successfully',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen.shade300,
        );
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snack);
      }
    }

Use this code it validates with using flutter package:
flutter_pw_validator: ^1.6.0
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
this is the best regx

bool passValid = RegExp("^(?=.{8,32}\$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%^&*(),.?:{}|<>]).*").hasMatch(value);
 
if (value.isEmpty ||!passValid) 
 {
 return 'error';
 }
```

Comment: regexp is wrong