# Write a Dart program to check whether a string is a valid password in dart

Tags: string, dart

**

> Write a Dart program to check whether a string is a valid password.

**

**a. A password must have at least ten character

b. A password consists of only letters and digits.

c. A password must contain at least two digits.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56253787/how-to-handle-textfield-validation-in-password-in-flutter

Comment: These questions end up requiring bad passwords,  Please challenge the people who ask for passwords like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  var password;
  stdout.write("Enter You'r Password: ");
  password=stdin.readLineSync();

   if(password.length>=10 && !password.contains(RegExp(r'\W')) && RegExp(r'\d+\w*\d+').hasMatch(password))
   {
     print(" \n\t$password is Valid Password");
   }
   else
   {
     print("\n\t$password is Invalid Password");

   }
```